# How to use node modules which are not yet installed without errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to prepare a setup script my NodeJS application.

It will:

- Create system roles for users
- Create root category for post
- And finally create system admin user for first login

And save that into a database.

But I also need the script to download NodeJS dependencies at the same time.

**setup.js**

```
/*
 * @author: Furkan Başaran <frknbasaran@gmail.com>
 * @date: 29.10.2015
 *
 * Application basic dependencies initalize script
 * */

var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

console.log("Newspaper IO - @FurkanBaşaran");
console.log("Tıme to take off");
console.log("Application Back-End dependencies installing..");
console.log("You may need enter root password in this stage")
exec("sudo npm install");

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var md5      = require('md5');


var UserSchema = require('./models/User');
var CategorySchema = require('./models/Category');
var RoleSchema = require('./models/Role');



/*
 * Create standart user roles
 * */
console.log("Step 1: Roles creating..");

/*
 * Create Mongoose Model from Schema
 * */
var RoleModel = mongoose.model('Role', RoleSchema);

/*
 * Create Role Instances
 * */
var Author = new RoleModel({"name": "Author"});
var Moderator = new RoleModel({"name": "Moderator"});
var Admin = new RoleModel({"name": "Admin"});

/*
 * Define an array object includes roles
 * */
var Roles = [Author, Moderator, Admin];

/*
 * Save standard roles to database
 * */
Roles.forEach(function (Role) {
    Role.save(function (err, role) {
        if (!err) console.log("Rol created: " + role.name);
        else console.log("Rol couldn't created, error: " + err)
    })
})

/*
 * Create Root Category Object
 * */
console.log("Step 2: Root category creating..")

/*
 * Create Mongoose Model from Schema
 * */
var CategoryModel = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);

/*
 * Create Root Category Object
 * */
var Root = new CategoryModel({"name": "Root"});

/*
 * Save category object into database
 * */
Root.save(function (err, root) {
    if (!err) console.log("Category created successfully:" + root.name)
    else console.log("Category couldn't created, error:" + err);
})

/*
* Create a admin user for first logIn
* */
console.log("Step 3: System Admin user account creating..")

/*
* Create Mongoose Model from Schema
* */
var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

/*
* Create User with admin privileges
* */
var SystemAdmin = new UserModel({"name":"System Admin", "username":"sysadmin", "email":"admin@willowsoft.com", "password": md5('mysecretpassword'), 'role': Admin});

/*
* Save System Admin user into database
* */
SystemAdmin.save(function(err, sysadmin) {
    if(!err) console.log("System Admin Account created, \nEmail: admin@willowsoft.com\nUsername: sysadmin");
})

console.log("Back-End Installation completed.");
console.log("Application Front-End dependencies initalizing..");
exec("cd public");
console.log("Bower Packages downloading..")
exec("bower install");
exec("gulp");
console.info("You can change application port and database connectionString on config.js file")
exec("cd ..");
console.log("MongoDB running up..");
exec("sudo mkdir database");
exec("sudo mongod --dbpath database");
console.log("Application starting with nodemon");
exec("sudo nodemon server");
```

Some possibilities to run this script without errors:

- I can check modules before requiring them and require if exist. (I've never seen anything like this before. Is this even possible?)
- First download the modules in this script, and have the completed processes require another file and use the modules in that file.
- Or I could run this command in a shell script and call the NodeJS file into that script. It will be easy but I'd like to learn the hard way if it's possible.

Any ideas or good ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback):

`exec` can take in a callback function as a parameter, meaning you can just do the following:

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

console.log("Newspaper IO - @FurkanBaşaran");
console.log("Tıme to take off");
console.log("Application Back-End dependencies installing..");
console.log("You may need enter root password in this stage")
exec("sudo npm install", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var md5      = require('md5');

    ... // etc
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I put together a quick script that uses npm to install the modules for you

```
var npm = require('npm');

npm.load(function(err, npm) {
  npm.commands.install(['require'], function(err, data) {
    console.log('dependencies installed');
  })
});
```